# How to convert Ballerina's native `json` to a `java.lang.Object`?

Tags: java, ballerina

I have a function that take's ballerina's native `json` object, and i'd like to pass it to a java function that i've created ballerina bindings for with `bal bindgen`.

The function is `ObjectMapper.writeValueAsBytes`, which takes a `java.lang.Object`.

How do I convert from `json` to `java.lang.Object`? in other words, what is `mysteryFunc` in the ballerina code block below?

```
function serialize(json input) returns byte[]|jackson2:JsonProcessingException|error  {
    msgpack:MessagePackMapper mapper = msgpack:newMessagePackMapper1();
    javalang:Object java_obj = mysteryFunc(input);
    return mapper.writeValueAsBytes(java_obj);
}
```

here's the bindgen command to generate the `MessagePackMapper` class:

```
bal bindgen -mvn org.msgpack:jackson-dataformat-msgpack:0.9.3 org.msgpack.jackson.dataformat.MessagePackMapper
```

edit: here's my latest attempt.

```
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/websocket;
import ballerina/jballerina.java;

function createJsonHandle(json data) returns handle = @java:Method {
    name: "createHandleValue",
    'class: "io.ballerina.runtime.api.creators.ValueCreator"
} external;

function createMsgpackMapperHandle() returns handle = @java:Constructor {
    'class: "org.msgpack.jackson.dataformat.MessagePackMapper"
} external;

function writeValueAsBytes(handle mapperObj, handle input) 
    returns handle|error = @java:Method {
    'class: "org.msgpack.jackson.dataformat.MessagePackMapper"
} external;

function encode(json input) returns byte[] | error {
    handle mapper = createMsgpackMapperHandle();
    handle input_handle = createJsonHandle(input);
    handle value = check writeValueAsBytes(mapper, input_handle);
    string? str_value = java:toString(value);
    return string:toBytes(str_value ?: "");
}
```

this compiles, however i get the java error:

```
error: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException {
"message":"iterator cannot be immutable (through reference chain: 
io.ballerina.runtime.internal.values.MapValueImpl["method"]->
io.ballerina.runtime.internal.values.BmpStringValue["iterator"]->
io.ballerina.runtime.internal.values.CharIterator["type"]->
io.ballerina.runtime.internal.types.BIteratorType["immutableType"]
)",
"cause":error(
"io.ballerina.runtime.internal.util.exceptions.BallerinaException",
message="iterator cannot be immutable"
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR, you need to create a `handle` value by wrapping the Ballerina value. Then use that handle value and create a Java object. Here is a sample code snippet.

There is no documented way to create a handle from a ballerina value. This looks like a gap in the interoperability support in Ballerina, and we will fix this in a future release.

```
import ballerina/jballerina.java;
import ballerina/io;

public function main() {
    json j = { "name": "John", "age": 30 };

    // Step 1: Create a handle from the ballerina value
    handle handleResult = createHandle(j);

    // Step 2: Create a new Object instance using the handle
    Object jsonObject = new(handleResult);

    io:println(jsonObject);
}

function createHandle(any data) returns handle = @java:Method {
    name: "createHandleValue",
    'class: "io.ballerina.runtime.api.creators.ValueCreator"
} external;
```

Comment: thank you for the response!  i'll mark this as accepted when i try this method.  right now i'm trying to replicate the "learn by example" walkthrough with my use case.

Comment: see my edit for the latest attempt.  it compiles, but i get an error about an immutable iterator.

Answer (score 0):

As per the code it uses Jackson databind to serialize the ballerina json object passed through java interop function. The serializer will serialize the whole object hierarchy of given ballerina json native object. So the it will try to serialize the type related objects in addition to json content too.

During the serialization, it will invoke all the Java getters for fields of the objects associated with the given json data. So the serializer tries to call 'getImmutableType' method from the iterator type during the process since the ballerina string contains an iterator. Since the ballerina iterator can not be immutable it will throw an exception.

Normal ballerina programs will never call the 'getImmutableType' method during runtime for iterators. We do not actually need to serialize the types and other java objects associated with the json data, only the content.

One option would be to customize the serialization logic with jackson databind. Another option would be to use the ballerina/serdes module as below.

```
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/serdes;

type Student record {
    int id;
    string name;
    decimal fees;
};

public function main() returns error? {
    json jsonValue = {
        id: 7894,
        name: "Waruna",
        fees: 24999.99
    };
    Student studentValue = check jsonValue.cloneWithType(Student);
    serdes:Proto3Schema serdes = check new (Student);
    byte[] serializedValue = check serdes.serialize(studentValue);
    Student deserializedValue = check 
    serdes.deserialize(serializedValue);
    io:println(deserializedValue);
}
```

Here ballerina serdes currently do not support json directly as per [1] so we need to map to a record and get the bytes.

[1] https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-standard-library/issues/4386